# How to make a total column that updates automatically in Access.

Tags: vba, ms-access, sum

In access I am trying to get my total value to be equal to the sum of the all of the different values where the order number is the same.

My current code is as follows;

```
= SUM( Forms![OrderLine]![Total] ) Where( Forms![OrderLine]![OrderNo]  = [OrderNo] )
```

This however gives me an error. How else would this be done?

Thanks

Comment: where is that formula ? in a report ? a query, a form ? the OrderLine form ? Is the OrderLine form open while you need that SUM ?

Comment: None of these are working because total isn't from a table, it is a calcuated value from a form

Comment: @Everton please provide the calculation. Are you calculating this on a single or a continuous form?

Comment: It is calculated on the orderline form using the calculation;  =[Quantity].[Value]*DLookUp("Price","Item","ItemID=" & [Forms]![OrderLine]![ItemID]) and I want to call it on the order form by summing all of the totals for one specific order

Comment: You could base your form datasource on a query that joins the currently use dtable with the Items table. This way you will avoid those slooow `DLookups`

Comment: Aggregate functions cannot reference controls, only fields. Would have to repeat the entire calc within the Sum() function.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an Order form and an OrderLine subform. Add a Form header/footer to your OrderLine form and put a text box in the footer. Put a SUM function in the Control Source of the footer text box to generate the aggregated value you need from the order line item rows.

On your main form, set the Control Source of the text box you want to display the order total equal to the name of the invisible text box in the subform. The control source on the main form text box will resemble SubformControlName.Form.AggregateTextBoxName.

You may need to play with the visibility settings of the header/footer, text box, form view mode, etc. to get the presentation you want, but this works even with the subform in datasheet view. The key is to get a text box somewhere on the subform to calculate the value you need on the parent form and then reference it inside the subform control from the parent form.